# Concatenate code object in Python

Tags: python

I'd like to gather multiple functions (the list is unknown) in a single one dynamicly, I fugured out how to create dynamicly a python function using types.FunctionType. 
However the first argument is a code object and cannot be a list of code object. How can I create a single function from multiple ones ?

thanks for your answer,
Jérôme

Comment: This sounds like one of those questions where the real answer to the real problem is much simpler than the answer to this question.  Where did you get the functions from? Why do you want to invoke them all one after the other? What do they do?

Comment: I'm using the weaver library in order to implement workflows. One workflow execution uses a python function as input. So I need one single function as input, However I'm trying to devide my code in workflow components that are represented as python function. So I do need a single function gathering all functions before the workflow compilation. But I guess the only solution is to over write there main class.

Comment: You don't have to overwrite their main class, you can define one Python function of your own that invokes all your smaller functions, no?

Comment: Yes this is what I'm doing now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about concatenating the code, I don't think you can reliably do that in python. You might consider chaining the functions together... something like this.

```
>>> def a(n):
    return n + 1

>>> def b(n):
    return n + 2

>>> funcs =[a,b]
>>> a = 0
>>> for f in funcs:
        a = f(a)


>>> print a
3
```